Error when using an external provider for mutation with gatekeeper
I am using version 3.17.1 of gatekeeper on my GKE cluster. I am using an "Assign" to mutate image containers to my desired image. I am using an external provider for that. My external provider is a flask deployment on the same cluster. In front of this deployment I have a service of type ClusterIP. I am using HTTPS for my provider. I generated the TLS cert as mentioned in the doc https://open-policy-agent.github.io/gatekeeper/website/docs/externaldata#how-to-generate-a-self-signed-ca-and-a-keypair-for-the-external-data-provider and added the base64 encoded CA bundle to my provider declaration.
After applying everything (my assign and provider), the mutation is not working although in the logs of my provider I see the HTTP Call coming for the webhook.
Part of the error I see in the logs of gatekeeper-controller is : "" failed to resolve external data placeholders: failed to send external data request to provider my-provider: failed to send external data request: Post "https://flask-app-service.default.svc.cluster.local/": context deadline exceeded" "" where "my-provider" is the name of my provider and "flask-app-service" is the name of my service's provider.
For info, my assign mutation is applied on pods, deployments and replicaSets :
apiVersion: mutations.gatekeeper.sh/v1beta1
kind: Assign
metadata:
  name: mutate-pod-images
spec:
 applyTo:
  - groups: [""]
    kinds: ["Pod"]
    versions: ["v1"]
  match:
    scope: Namespaced
  location: "spec.containers[name:*].image"
  parameters:
    assign:
     externalData:
       provider: my-provider
       dataSource: ValueAtLocation
---

apiVersion: mutations.gatekeeper.sh/v1beta1\
kind: Assign
metadata:
  name: mutate-deploy-images
spec:
  applyTo:
  - groups: ["apps"]
    kinds: ["Deployment"]
    versions: ["v1"]
  match:
    scope: Namespaced
  location: "spec.template.spec.containers[name:*].image"
  parameters:
    assign:
      externalData:
        provider: my-provider
        dataSource: ValueAtLocation

---

    apiVersion: mutations.gatekeeper.sh/v1beta1
    kind: Assign
    metadata:
      name: mutate-rs-images
    spec:
      applyTo:
      - groups: ["apps"]
        kinds: ["ReplicaSet"]
        versions: ["v1"]
      match:
        scope: Namespaced
      location: "spec.template.spec.containers[name:*].image"
      parameters:
        assign:
          externalData:
            provider: my-provider
            dataSource: ValueAtLocation

I don't understand why the mutation is not working nor why gatekeeper-controller says "failed to resolve external data request" although in my logs I it made the request.
The request my provider received is this :
{'apiVersion': 'externaldata.gatekeeper.sh/v1beta1', 'kind': 'ProviderRequest', 'request': {'keys': ['<my deployment image>']}}

and the response my provider's sends back is this :
{'apiVersion': 'externaldata.gatekeeper.sh/v1beta1', 'kind': 'ProviderResponse', 'response': {'idempotent': True, 'items': [{'key': '<my deployment image>', 'value': '<my desired image>'}]}}

Anyone has any idea what's the issue please ? Thank you so much in advance.

I think I found the issue. In case this helps someone. I had to change the timeout of the mutation webhook. The assign type is after all a mutation webhook. Its timeout is configured to 1 second which is short if our provider takes time.
